# Magento 2.2.2 upgrade 2.3.2 PHP 7.2 MCRYPT_BLOWFISH pecl

Tags: php, server-setup, centos, linux

> Centos 6
>   Apache 2.4
>
> PHP 7.2

I am trying to complete the upgrade of the Magento 2.2.2 store to Magento 2.3 following this tutorial

> https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/how-to-upgrade-from-magento-2-2-8-to-2-3-1/528

However, I am getting the following error in CLI and Frontend and Admin at step 4.5 running

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> [Exception]   Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH -
>   assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH' (this will throw an Error i   n a future
>   version of PHP) in
>   /home/redjohnco/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.ph
>   p on line 397

I am checking a lot of post since last 2 days online and see that in PHP7 7.2 mcrypt has been removed -

However, it seems Magento 2.3 or (my upgrade seems to need it)

I have a lot of posts on this and they mention it can be installed on PHP 7.2 However the instructions don't seem to work on my Linux Centos 6

all the packages mentioned in the posts whenever I run give output

> No package libc-dev available.
>
> No package pkg-config available.
>
> No package mcrypt-1.0.1 available.

It seems it can't find the package or whatever it needs to install mcrypt for PHP 7.2

Please note I am using multiple versions of PHP on my server but when I'm checking in CLI SSH `php-v` I can see the version 7.2 is being used -

I switch using MultiPHP Manager

Also, I am using WHM CPANEL on the server

I have tried using this too

> https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/

and similar other tutorials

The problem I get is when I try and run this command

```
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

I keep getting

> -bash: pecl: command not found

Please can anyone advise how I can fix this on centos 6

Comment: have tried this solution **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625161/peclcommand-not-found/1625235**

Comment: thanks - yes I already have pear installed and enabled